# Transcendence of sum of reciprocals of factorials

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, transcendental-number-theory

For $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, define $\displaystyle x_A = \sum_{n \in A} \frac{1}{n!}$. It is easy to see that for every infinite $A$, $x_A$ is irrational.

**Question**: Is there an infinite $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ for which $\displaystyle x_A = \sum_{n \in A} \frac{1}{n!}$ is algebraic?

Comment: Exactly this class of numbers is proved irrational (and some examples given, which I think all happen to be transcendental) in Martin Griffiths, "Irrational sums from reciprocals of factorials", Math. Gaz. 2015, https://www.jstor.org/stable/24496963

Comment: I suspect the answer is no but that a proof is beyond current technology. The proof that $e$ is transcendental relies on special properties of the function $e^x$, not just on the rate of growth of $n!$. There are transcendence results that rely only on how fast the summands shrink but they require a faster growth rate than $n!$. For example, [Nyblom](https://doi.org/10.1006/jnth.2001.2672) proves that if for some fixed $\lambda>2$ we have $\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}/a_n^{λ+1}>1$ then $\sum_n 1/a_n$ is transcendental.

Comment: For other results along these lines, see [Kumar and Vance](https://doi.org/10.1017/S0004972719000194) and the references therein. I'm not familiar with them all but at first glance they all require faster growth rates than $n!$. And for an arbitrary $A$ it seems to me that there's not much you can say about $\sum_{n\in A} 1/n!$ other than the general rate at which the summands shrink.

Comment: At least we can prove that if $x_{A}$ is an algebraic number then $A$ is not a cofinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$. :)